# Ceph alertmanager config

Tags: ceph, prometheus

I've installed `ceph` using `cephadm`

Including monitoring stack `prometheus`, `alertmanager`, `node-exporter`

Currently I'm trying to add a `telegram` receiver (Telegram is supported from v0.24.0, so I've manually updated `mgr/container_image_alertmanager` fro 0.23 to 0.24) for `alertmanager`, but can't find in docs where `alertmanager.yml` should be created.

I can see this file is created inside ceph cluster `/var/lib/ceph/{hash}/alertmanager.ceph-1/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml`

I've added the config to the above file as below:

```yaml
templates:
  - '/etc/alertmanager/config/*.tmpl'
route:
  receiver: 'default'
  routes:
    - group_by: ['alertname']
      group_wait: 10s
      group_interval: 10s
      repeat_interval: 30m
      receiver: 'telegram'
receivers:
- name: 'default'
  webhook_configs:
- name: 'ceph-dashboard'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'https://ceph-1:8443/api/prometheus_receiver'
- name: 'telegram'
  telegram_configs:
    - bot_token: <bot_token>
      chat_id: <chat_id>
      send_resolved: true
      parse_mode: 'HTML'
      api_url: 'https://api.telegram.org'
      message: '{{ template "telegram.text" . }}'
```

[image]

The receiver works fine, but after redeploying the `alertmanager` from Ceph dashboard the config is gone, and is logical, becuase I'm editing generated file.

Please if anyone can assist and/or point to correct direction where I should create alertmanager config to extend/override the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [ceph manual](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/services/monitoring/) regarding its monitoring, there's this part about using custom configuration for components of the stack.

```
Option names

The following templates for files that will be generated by cephadm can be overridden. These are the names to be used when storing with `ceph config-key set`:
 - services/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml
 - services/grafana/ceph-dashboard.yml
 - services/grafana/grafana.ini
 - services/prometheus/prometheus.yml
 - services/prometheus/alerting/custom_alerts.yml
 - services/loki.yml
 - services/promtail.yml

You can look up the file templates that are currently used by cephadm in src/pybind/mgr/cephadm/templates:
 - services/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml.j2
 - services/grafana/ceph-dashboard.yml.j2
 - services/grafana/grafana.ini.j2
 - services/prometheus/prometheus.yml.j2
 - services/loki.yml.j2
 - services/promtail.yml.j2
```

Simply take the ceph template, edit it to your liking and `ceph config-key set` it as the template to use when generating alert manager's configuration.